# Trying to decode a Public Key

Tags: java, key, decode, x509, public

I've got some problems with decoding a public key in my android project.

I am trying to decode my own public key, so I can save all the different informations and use the public key for encryption and to sign it. But I am still stuck in the decode part.

```js
keystring =
                    "mQCNBFg6zDoBBAC+eadQCpaNjd/3cei2TafVYddN93cPo+e/xMi2lcVSIqEKT9eT" +
                    "bERLwqFbddXwyYQ8p1WoL7unRk3EHPP0CW+8FCJYoL4B9rDu2B3oDojsRFg0dsS4" +
                    "Znk7GJ8uR9zZmlW+K474VZXYk7otPuncAjFkP1Ywcb1ZTBcA5wRpDp8PIQARAQAB" +
                    "tCxUb2JpYXMgQnVjaGJlcmdlciA8ZGFuaWVsLmJ1Y2hiZXJnZXJAZ214LmF0PokB" +
                    "DAQQAQIAdgUCWDrMPjAUgAAAAAAgAAdwcmVmZXJyZWQtZW1haWwtZW5jb2RpbmdA" +
                    "cGdwLmNvbXBncG1pbWUICwkIBwMCAQoCGQEZGGxkYXA6Ly9rZXlzZXJ2ZXIucGdw" +
                    "LmNvbQUbAwAAAAUWAAMCAQUeAQAAAAYVCAkKAwIACgkQy6KPS3KUaIHLewQAkUbk" +
                    "j1Zx2FQtX2ThwdK4eh2PuEYKjMOreWh0b7AO6xaA+XuLr5K+iho7am5CHPBoBSaL" +
                    "kEOThvtMK0jkHLXC5hFlUpkl1rp5ZP7K9mixG8KwN+1Xhxr5BAkLLDZDgrTRBPQz" +
                    "Mw87vFmjdhnYS+KmXzZJZ1bb1SJOPg/bmQIG6su5AI0EWDrMOgEEAOICdmrP3voZ" +
                    "3/zFHS1x/DVVJUYiD2/t+ChtY2RcKi4/GH4ZIDs2NQdX+3YABdBsZ57YIWtFHmDC" +
                    "/TJ0VSdhEZ+Rlw8Yr/5IBiVvpx9cqYjk8oRD/ck5F4soCBO6N+e76ck4v3WlmlnE" +
                    "Lb6BuPywdwNdapseY+0fvRJVshrGyCvpABEBAAGJAUAEGAECAKoFAlg6zDsFGwwA" +
                    "AACdIAQZAQgABgUCWDrMOgAKCRDeSTNawFdQ5B6TA/967XBC+1cNzLcOyPVW5mQU" +
                    "TzmI2NclvUVstlJTOvWFA5LhgOrkeZpxIQeJQs8BkoFjC7Sn55T2eU4nwFfwkGaO" +
                    "u+72hgxphOendSbuFfQvnGILDV/Jzi9Nx6jicSjJaBJVX0AOIA8c9JGhCBftT/Mt" +
                    "5ngetYMkSOeujkQLw6CV9AAKCRDLoo9LcpRogQ96BACKvKcshGvdehZCr/l01vxb" +
                    "EhfzTzA0pz2SheZKnDfiRaauTDqe8mJmetLQ/s5pMg6BlJ7zY354ZWfIe4M44zc8" +
                    "l7nVZtnTnbNSxJ/5hIwAvS6rVQwKr40F9aximg0xFImcHkbVDV4v18eDJchhHUDo" +
                    "rxcxQT2Ao1UYC8KqjxvuZQ==";

                    byte[] decodeValue = Base64.decode(keystring, Base64.DEFAULT);

                    //logs
                    Log.d("TEST", "defaultValue = " + keystring);
                    Log.d("TEST", "decodeValue = " + new String(decodeValue));
                   
                    X509EncodedKeySpec pubKeySpec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(decodeValue);
                    try {
                        KeyFactory keyFact = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
                        try {
                            PublicKey publicKey = keyFact.generatePublic(pubKeySpec);
                            schluessel = "schluessel";
                            Log.d("TEST", "publicKey = " + publicKey.toString());
                            Log.d("TEST", "Algorithm = " + publicKey.getAlgorithm());
                            Log.d("TEST", "Format = " + publicKey.getFormat());
                        }
                        catch (InvalidKeySpecException  e) {
                            System.err.println("Error with KeySpec!");
                        }
                    }
                    catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
                        System.err.println("Error with Algorithm!");
                    }
```

So right now I get the InvalidKeySpecException and I don't know why. I tried various Specs but as far as I know the X509 should be the one I am using. 
In my code I remove the "-----BEGIN PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----" and the "-----End PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----" parts, the checksum and the version - then I decode the Armor Ascii part with BASE64 and save it to a string.

Am I wrong? Which Specs do I need? Which Specs would I need when saving the whole Key Block (including the BEGIN and END) in file/string?

I am really desperate right now and thankful for every help! Thx :)

Comment: Have you looked at what the InvalidKeySpecException message is?

Comment: @Derek_M I only see my defined InvalidKeySpecException string

Comment: Well the details in InvalidKeySpecException should give you at least some clues, or "google-able" things to look for.

Comment: @Derek_M in the Android Monitor I only see the "Error with KeySpec!" system print, that I defined in the code..

Comment: Right, you can change that though. You could change the System error message to `System.err.println(e.getMessage())` for example in your generate public key try block. Also, you can get the stack trace, etc there as well.

Comment: @Derek_M thank you! Now I see the error message "error:0c0890ba:ASN.1 encoding routines:asn1_check_tlen:WRONG_TAG" saying it's not DER encoded if I get it right, it is DER encoded.. I am so confused..

Comment: I can't quite remember, since it has been awhile since have worked with PGP, but have you tried keeping the BEGIN PGP and END PGP headers and close, instead of removing it?